# Performance issue with the Active Record type map query after upgrading to rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

> ###### TL;DR
>
> The intent of this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/42ce7057c682b3053964de7e802a5b4463137190) on `Active Record` was to make the initial type map query less expensive but after upgrading from rails 6.1.7 to 7.0.4 this query is taking way longer than its previous version and I can't figure out why.

### Edit

As jjanes suggested in the answer below, upgrading to PostgreSQL 14 solved the issue.

After the upgrade the execution time decreased from 9656.222 ms to 60.618 ms

---

After an upgrade to rails 7.0.4 (was using 6.1.7) we faced some performance issues with our
Postgresql instance on Amazon RDS. After the deploy the CPU usage reached 100% and the instance went down.

[image]

Looking at the db logs I saw a lot of occurencies of the type map query, which is triggered when a
new connection to the DB is created.

[image]

Our `log_min_duration_statement` is set to 10000, so it will log any statement that takes longer than 10 seconds.

Before the rails upgrade I saw the type map query few times in a day whith an average duration of 11 seconds.
After the upgrade I saw it constatly whith the duration varying between 13 seconds and 90 seconds.

I put both queries in a gist with the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

- [rails 7](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/bb4aa460af55bbe0bb54f9d0aa594eda)
- [rails 6 (pre-update)](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/373a59d3d95da3d395e5fa7552473ec1)

I noticed this commit changes the type map query to be less expensive but it did the opposite in our application.

The problem seems to be the statment generated by the method [query_conditions_for_known_type_types](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/type_map_initializer.rb#L44)

Currently we're using:

- rails 7.0.4 (upgrading form 6.1.7)
- ruby 3.1.2
- PostgreSQL 13.7 on Amazon RDS
- multitenant database where each tenant has its own schema in a single database. (around 2000 schemas)
- ros-apartment gem
- good_job with 20 threads and external execution mode

Any ideas on why we're seeing this performance issue in this query?

Comment: Could you expose the entire query someplace, as text rather than an image?  What was the similar pre-update query?

Comment: @jjanes sure, I put them in a gist: 
[rails 7](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/bb4aa460af55bbe0bb54f9d0aa594eda)
[rails 6](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/373a59d3d95da3d395e5fa7552473ec1)

Comment: What is the version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: @jjanes version 13.7

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  After creating 2000 schemas with 5 tables each (to make ~10000 custom pg_types, about the number in your IN-list) it only took 184ms to run the query.  Can you capture the execution plans, by using auto_explain.log_analyze and auto_explain.log_min_duration rather than using log_min_duration_statement?  Or just by running the captured queries manually with `EXPLAIN (ANAALYZE, BUFFERS)` in front.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for your help. I updated the gists with the result. [Rails 6](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/373a59d3d95da3d395e5fa7552473ec1?permalink_comment_id=4346644#gistcomment-4346644) - [Rails 7](https://gist.github.com/jorgearimitsu/bb4aa460af55bbe0bb54f9d0aa594eda?permalink_comment_id=4346640#gistcomment-4346640). I used `blazer` to execute them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IN-list against a giant list of constants did not get optimized to a hash table lookup until PostgreSQL v14.  So it is not surprising that this query sucks in v13.

I don't know if they didn't test this ROR change against older versions of PostgreSQL, or didn't test with a pg_type table as large as yours or a IN-list as long as yours, or what. I don't know much about ROR, I'm just looking at the PostgreSQL side of things

My original simulations didn't reproduce the problem because I assumed the size of the pg_type table was about the same as the size of the IN-list, but obviously that is a bad assumption, as shown by the `Rows Removed by Filter:` lines.

Maybe the easiest solution, assuming you can't/don't want to reverse this ROR change, would be to migrate to PostgreSQL v14.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I will update to v14 next week and see what happens.